# How to parse multiple root "n" nodes in xml and extract root text value in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath

I am trying to use lxml and xpath to extracting xml package that stored in a database. Each record has same xml structure except "C" some C has 3 values-nodes , something has more ..

[image]

Steve has 3 "C" value , while Mel has 5 "C" , I would like to find a way in python to get the final table that would print out C without [' '] and store data under C variable , and also extract C in a way that it would flag "is_R1" = 1

```
B = etree.xPath('/a/b/text()')(root)[0]
C = etree.xPath('/a/b/x/c/text()')(root)
C0 = etree.xPath('/a/b/x/c/text()')(root)[0]
C1 = etree.xPath('/a/b/x/c/text()')(root)[1] 
C2
C3
:
:
Cn

print B,C,C0,C1,C2,...Cn
```

Now I can see this below when I print

[image]

But my problem is each record has different "n"

My final output that I am trying to accomplish is something like ..

[image]

Comment: This post needs more [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Comment: JPC, So, would you want the result to be an HTML table, or what?

Comment: I like my result to be stored in variable B, C , is_R1 , is_R2 ... isRn

Comment: I will then connect to the other database connection and store them to another server, but I got that part down .. just have to crack this bit and stored them to B,C,is_R1, is_R2, ... is_Rn and so on